# MSTEST: How do I create files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I have an app that is watching a file directory and then doing some work when it sees files of a certain type (sending off a message to a web service).
Before I create the app, I'm creating some tests. To setup the tests, I want to create 3 files. For teardown, I want to remove those files.

In a normal console app, this code works fine, but in MSTEST, I get the following error

Message: Initialization method XXX threw exception. `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:` Could not find a part of the path 'C:\repos\MyProjects.Project1\TestResults\some_testrun_unique_folder\Out\Tests\0950\file1.txt'..

**How do I work with MSTEST's directories for file creation?**

```
public class FileWatcherTests
{
    string _testPath = @"Tests\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm");
    string[] _testFiles = new[] { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        CreateFiles(_testPath, _testFiles);
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        RemoveFiles(_testPath, _testFiles);
    }


    void CreateFiles(string path, string[] fileNames)
    {
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            var fullName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            File.WriteAllText(
                path: fullName,
                contents: "Some Random Text");
        }
    }
    void RemoveFiles(string path, string[] fileNames)
    {
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            var fullName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            File.Delete(fullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the containing folder before trying to write the file.

Inside the `CreateFiles` method, you could do this:

```
var parentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(parentFolder);
```

Note: You don't need to bother checking if the folder exists, because `CreateDirectory` will do that for you.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there isn't much different in creating files under `MsTest` as opposed to a console application. In console applications the working directory is usually `./bin/debug` and under `MsTest` it is the long file path you got in the exception.

With that out of the way, why did you get an exception? Because the directory `Tests` does not exist under the current working directory, all you need to do is to create that directory which you can do with [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I miscopied code over from my console app to the test project, which happened to be exactly what John reported as the answer.